# É possível usar 3 webcams de uma só vez usando Flash AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, câmera

Estou usando o código abaixo para exibir 3 webcams de uma só vez.
Mas só funciona com 2.

> `getCamera("0")` e `getCamera("1")` = ok
>   `getCamera("1")` e `getCamera("2")` = ok
>   `getCamera("0")` e `getCamera("2")` = ok
>   `getCamera("0")` e `getCamera("1")` e `getCamera("2")` = não

Não aparece erro nenhum, simplesmente não aparece no palco.

```
var cameras = Camera.names;
trace('Cameras: '+cameras);

// Cameras: Microsoft® LifeCam HD-3000,Integrated Webcam,USB2.0 Camera,IP Camera [JPEG/MJPEG]
// Camera.getCamera("0") = Microsoft® LifeCam HD-3000
// Camera.getCamera("1") = Integrated Webcam
// Camera.getCamera("2") = USB2.0 Camera

var camera0:Camera = Camera.getCamera("0");
camera0.setMode(400, 300, 100); 
camera0.setQuality(0,100);
var video0:Video = new Video(); 
video0.smoothing = true;
video0.width = 400;
video0.height = 300;
video0.x=0;
video0.y=0;
video0.attachCamera(camera0);
addChild(video0);

var camera1:Camera = Camera.getCamera("1");
camera1.setMode(400, 300, 100); 
camera1.setQuality(0,100);
var video1:Video = new Video(); 
video1.smoothing = true;
video1.width = 400;
video1.height = 300;
video1.x=400;
video1.y=0;
video1.attachCamera(camera1);
addChild(video1);

var camera2:Camera = Camera.getCamera("2");
camera2.setMode(400, 300, 100); 
camera2.setQuality(0,100);
var video2:Video = new Video(); 
video2.smoothing = true;
video2.width = 400;
video2.height = 300;
video2.x=800;
video2.y=0;
video2.attachCamera(camera2);
addChild(video2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Isso pode ser um consumo de banda das portas USB do seu computador, segundo [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16510741/as3-multiple-webcams-not-showing-3rd-webcam) do SOen.

Segundo a tradução da resposta do próprio OP, ao realizar um teste conectando a terceira webcam à uma porta usb de outro computador, funcionou corretamente.

Outro teste que ele fez foi iniciar a câmera com um tamanho e qualidade menor.

Segundo [este post](http://www.flashforum.de/forum/flash-cs5-professional/cs6-as3-multi-webcam-fotoaufname-303548.html) de um fórum, as três webcams funcionaram ao iniciar com o formato padrão, sem nenhuma alteração de qualidade e tamanho com o código abaixo:

```
var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera("0"); 
var vid:Video = new Video(); 
vid.attachCamera(cam); 
v1.addChild(vid);

var cam1:Camera = Camera.getCamera("1"); 
var vid1:Video = new Video(); 
vid1.attachCamera(cam1); 
v2.addChild(vid1);

var cam2:Camera = Camera.getCamera("2"); 
var vid2:Video = new Video(); 
vid2.attachCamera(cam2); 
v3.addChild(vid2);
```

Pode ser algum recurso de hardware que esteja faltando.